# AWS SageMaker models popping in and out of the vacuum

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I have proven quantum mechanics while trying to deploy and use an AWS SageMaker Models. Notice the errors seem to indicate that the model/endpoint both do and don't exist.

#### Training my model

```
m = MXNet("lstm_trainer.py", 
          role=role, 
          train_instance_count=10, 
          train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
          hyperparameters={'batch_size': 100, 
                         'epochs': 400, 
                         'learning_rate': 0.1, 
                         'momentum': 0.9, 
                         'log_interval': 100})
m.fit(inputs)
```

runs fine.

#### Deploying the endpoint

```
predictor = m.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

gets the error,

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Cannot create already existing model "arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:01234567890:model/sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-02-13-17-18-59-047".
```

#### Running the endpoint,

```
predictor.predict(np.arange(100))
```

gives,

```
ValidationError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Endpoint sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-02-13-17-18-59-047 of account 01234567890 not found.
```

#### Deleting the endpoint like,

```
sagemaker.Session().delete_endpoint(predictor.endpoint)
```

gives,

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteEndpoint operation: Could not find endpoint "arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:01234567890:endpoint/sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-02-13-17-18-59-047".
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi aidan, even i am getting same error...if you funded any  solution please help me."https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047576/amazon-sagemake-throwing-error-building-your-own-algorithm-container-execution-t"