# Amazon SageMake throwing error Building your own algorithm container execution time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run my own algorithm container in amazon sagemaker,at the time of deployment time ,I am getting error like below.

```
predictor = tree.deploy(1, 'ml.m4.xlarge', serializer=csv_serializer)

ValueError: Error hosting endpoint decision-trees-sample-2018-03-01-09-59-06-832: Failed Reason:  The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check.
```

then I run same line of code this time i am getting  below error.

```
 predictor = tree.deploy(1, 'ml.m4.xlarge', serializer=csv_serializer)

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: Cannot create already existing endpoint "arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:69759707XXxXX:endpoint/decision-trees-sample-2018-03-01-09-59-06-832".
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this issue: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/210

@djarpin wrote:

> The ping health check message is a general error that can be caused by several different issues. Typically the error message in the CloudWatch log group named /aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/ will provide a more detailed description of why the ping health check didn't pass.

Hope that helps!